# Using Powershell to remove illegal CRLF from csv row

Tags: powershell, ssis, etl

Gentle Reader,

I have a year's worth of vendor csv files sitting in a directory.  My task is to load them into a SQL Server DB as a "Historical Load".  The files are mal-formed and while we are working with the vendor to re-send 365 new, properly structured files, I have been tasked with trying to work with what we have.

I'm restricted to using either C# (as a script task in SSIS) or Powershell.

Each file has no header but the schema is known and built into the SSIS package connection.

Each file has approx 35k rows and roughly a few dozen mal-formed rows per file.

Each properly formed row consists of 122 columns, 121 comma's.

Rows are NOT text qualified.

Example: (data cleaned of PII)

```
555222,555222333444,1,HN71232,1/19/2018 8:58:07 AM,3437,27.50,HECTOR EVERYMAN,25-Foot Garden Hose - ,1/03/2018 10:17:24 AM,,1835,,,,,online,,MERCH,1,MERCH,MI,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6611060033556677,2526677,,,,,,,,,,,,,,EVERYMAN,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,VWDEB,,,,,,,555666NA118855,2/22/2018 12:00:00 AM,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2121,,,1/29/2018 9:50:56 AM,0,,,[CRLF]
555222,555222444888,1,CASUAL50,1/09/2018 12:00:00 PM,7000,50.00,JANE SMITH,$50 Casual Gift Card,1/19/2018 8:09:15 AM,1/29/2018 8:19:25 AM,1856,,,,,online,,FREE,1,CERT,GC,,,,,,,6611060033553311[CRLF]
,6611060033553311[CRLF]
,,,,,,,,,25,,,6611060033556677,2556677,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,CASUAL25,VWDEB,,,,,,,555222NA118065,1/22/2018 12:00:00 AM,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1/19/2018 12:00:15 PM,0,,,[CRLF]
555222,555222777666,1,CASHCS,1/12/2018 10:31:43 AM,2500,25.00,BOB SMITH,BIG BANK Rewards Cash Back Credit [...6S66],,,1821,,,,,online,,CHECK,1,CHECK,CK,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,555222166446,5556677,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,VWDEB,,,1/23/2018 10:30:21 AM,,,,555666NA118844,1/22/2018 12:00:00 AM,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1/22/2018 10:31:26 AM,0,,,[CRLF]
```

Powershell Get-Content (I think...) reads until file into an array where each row is identified by the CRLF as the terminator.  This means (again, I think) that mal-formed rows will be treated as an element of the array without respect to how many "columns" it holds.

C# Streamreader also uses CRLF as a marker but a streamreader object also has a few methods available like Peek and Read that may be useful.

Please, Oh Wise Ones, point me in the direction of least resistance.  Using Powershell, as a script to process mal-formed csv files such that CRLFs that are not EOL are removed.

Thank you.

Comment: No disrespect in intended.  This solution will be a hot mess.  Can you an output without the extra {CRLF}.  This appears that you copy and pasted information from the command line or a program thus the extra [CRLF].  Assuming that this cannot be done.  We have problem that your longest lines are 353.  Please ensure that the length in which it word wraps is correct.  We only have a chance of parsing this IF there is a very easy to understand pattern.

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  I copied this from Notepad++ and added the CRLF for visual cue.  Agreed, this is a hot mess.

Comment: Turn off line wrap in Notepad++.  at the top menu select "View".  Click on "Word Wrap".  Clean data for PII.  If you delete a character replace it on for one. Copy and paste information into your question. Note in the question that you made an edit.

Comment: If you have column headers.  Import-csv will save you.  Does the top line have names for the columns?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what way some rows are "malformed"?

Comment: Would it just happen that the extra crlf resides in, say, address field and is used to separate multiple address lines that should go together in one database column? This will cause massive problems if one row has two address lines and another has three. In such a case, it's pretty much GIGO.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that (i) all rows are correctly terminated with a crlf (ii) there are no commas in field data? If so, you could manually read text lines one at a time, split them on comma and accumulate them in an array until you have a row’s worth of values (121?), then process the row, and start accumulating values again.

Comment: Thank you all for your questions and interest.  The example provided shows 3 rows, the top and bottom rows are correctly formatted with the CRLF row terminator at the End Of the Line.  The middle row has 3 CRLF's embedded within a single row.  There are no commas in field data.  I thought I was pretty clear in my explanation and thorough in my prior research but at least one person downvoted my question.  I will try harder next time. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) design but in (Native¹) PowerShell:

```
$Delimiters  =  121
Get-Content .\OldFile.csv |ForEach-Object { $Line = '' } {
    if ($Line) { $Line += ',' + $_ } else { $Line = $_ }
    $TotalMatches = ($Line |Select-String ',' -AllMatches).Matches.Count
    if ($TotalMatches -ge $Delimiters ) {
        $Line
        $Line = ''
    }
} |Set-Content .\NewFile.Csv
```

<sub>1) I guess performance might be improved by avoiding `+=` and using dot .net methods along with text streamers</sub>

Comment: Thank you @iRon. This was exactly what I was looking for and it works as expected. Much love from the Sonoran Desert.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your best bet is to get good data from the supplier. Trying to work around a mess will just cause problems later on. Garbage in, garbage out. Since it's you who wrote the garbage data in the database, congratulations, it's now your fault that the DB data is of poor quality. Please talk with your manager and the stakeholders first, so that you have in writing an agreement that you didn't break the data and it was broken to start with. I've seen such problems on ETL processing all too often.

A quick and dirty pseudocode without error handling, edge case processing, substring index assumptions, performance guarantees and whatnot  goes like so,

```
while(dataInFile)
  line = readline()

  :parseLine

  commasInLine = countCommas(line)

  if commasInLine == rightAmount
    addLineInOKBuffer(line)
  else
    commasNeeded = rightAmount - commasInLine

  if commasNeeded < 0
    # too many commas, two lines are combined
    lastCommaLocation = getLastCommaIndex(line, commasNeeded)
    addLineInOKBuffer(line.substring(0, lastCommaLocation)
    line = line.substring(lastCommaLocation, line.end)
    goto :parseline
  else 
    # too few lines, need to read next line too
    line = line.removeCrLf() + readline()
    goto :parseline
```

The idea is that first you look for a line and count how many commas there are. If the count matches what's expected, the row is not broken. Store it in a buffer containing good data.

If you have too many commas, then the row contains at least two different elements. Then find the index of where the first element ends, extract it and store it in the good data buffer. Then remove already processed part of the line and start again.

If you have too few commas, then the row is splitted by a newline. Read the next line from the file, join it with the current line and start the parsing again from counting the lines.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time, vonPryz.  I appreciate your answer.